# Loop through folders in subdirectories and combine text files

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

I am wanting to loop through folders within a subdirectory and combine all text files into one file. I found some answers online but none seems to work. Any help is much appreciated. I have provided what I've found below. In the example below the `DummyFolder` has multiple subdirectories that contain `.txt files` that need to be merged into 1 file. I got code 3 to work yesterday but somehow I changed something and it is no longer working for some reason.

Code 1:

```
@echo off
set "header=C:\Users\user\Desktop\DummyFolder\Headings.txt"
set "folder=C:\Users\user\Desktop\DummyFolder\"
set "tempFile=%folder%\temp.txt"
for %%F in ("%folder%\*.txt") do (
   type "%header%" >"%tempFile%"
   type "%%F" >>"%tempFile%"
   move /y "%tempFile%" "%%F" >nul
)
```

Also found this code (Code 2):

```
$startingDir = 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\DummyFolder\'
$combinedDir = 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\DummyFolder\CombinedTextFiles'

Get-ChildItem $startingDir -Recurse | Where-Object {
   $txtfiles = Join-Path $_.FullName '*.txt'
   $_.PSIsContainer -and (Test-Path $txtfiles)
} | ForEach-Object {
   $merged = Join-Path $combinedDir ($_.Name + '_Merged.txt')
   Get-Content $txtfiles | Set-Content $merged
}
```

Also found this code (Code 3):

```
@echo on
set folder="C:\Users\user\Desktop\DummyFolder\"
for /F %%a in ('dir /b /s %folder%') do (
   if "%%~xa" == ".txt" (
      (echo/------------------------------
      type %%~a
      echo/)>>"%~dp0list.txt"
   )
)
```

Comment: "It is no longer working for some reason" -- please elaborate on that; what do you wnat to achieve exactly, and what do you actually get? Where are your source files located? in the given folder `DummyFolder`, in its immediate sub-folders, or anywhere under `DummyFolder`? And what about the header part? I assume you want it to be copied once to the resulting file, right?

Answer (score 1):

In CMD you'd do something like this:

```
@echo off

set "basedir=C:\some\folder"
set "outfile=C:\path\to\output.txt"

(for /r "%basedir%" %f in (*.txt) do type "%~ff") > "%outfile%"
```

For use in batch files you need to change `%f` to `%%f` and `%~ff` to `%%~ff`.

---

In PowerShell you'd do something like this:

```
$basedir = 'C:\some\folder'
$outfile = 'C:\path\to\output.txt'

Get-ChildItem $basedir -Include *.txt -Recurse | Get-Content |
    Set-Content $outfile
```

Answer (score 0):

Code 3 is not bad but it won't work with spaces in a path because you use the standard `delims` as you're not providing one. Also there a several other errors about working with spaces in a path.

The following code works and combine all `txt files` in all subdirectories. It will create a new file `list.txt` in the folder where this batch file is located. If there is already an existing `list.txt` it will be overwritten. Note that it's a batch file:

```cmd
@echo off
set "folder=C:\Users\user\Desktop\DummyFolder\"
rem create new empty file: list.txt in directory of batch file: %~dp0
break>"%~dp0list.txt"
rem loop through all output lines of the dir command, unset delimns
rem so that space will not separate
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /s "%folder%"') do (
   rem just look for txt files
   if "%%~xa" == ".txt" (
      rem don't use the list.txt
      if not "%%a" == "%~dp0list.txt" (
         rem append the output of the whole block into the file
         (echo/------------------------------
         type "%%a"
         echo/)>>"%~dp0list.txt"
      )
   )
)
```

If you don't understand something it's quite easy to find something good on the internet because there are several great batch scripting sites. Further you can always use `echo This is a message visible on the command prompt` to display something that might be useful e.g. variables etc. With that you can "debug" and look what happens.
Some explanations beyond the comments (`rem This is a comment`) in the code:

**1.
`break` command:**

To clear a file I use the break command which will produce no output at all. That empty output I redirect to a file, read it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19633987/8051589.

**2.
General variables:**

You set variables via `set varname=Content` I prefer the way as I do it with quotes: `set "varname=Content"` as it works with redirection characters also. Use the variable with one starting `%` and one trailing `%` e.g. `echo %varname%`. You can read a lot of it on https://ss64.com/nt/set.html. I think ss64 is probably the best site for batch scripting out there.

**3.
Redirection `>` and `>>`:**

You can redirect the output of a command with `>` or `>>` where `>` creates a new file and overwrites existing files and `>>` appends to a file or create one if not existing. There are a lot more thing possible: https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html.

**4.
`for /f` loop:**

In a batch file you loop through the lines of a command output by using a `for /f` loop. The variable that is used will be written with 2 `%` in front of it, here `%%a`. I also set the delimiter `delimns` to nothing so that the command output will not be separated into several tokens.
You can read a lot of details about a `for /f` loop at: https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html.

**5.
Special variable syntax `%%~xa` and `%~dp0`:**

The variable `%%a` which hold one line of the `dir` command can be expand to the file extension only via: `%%~xa` as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5034119/8051589. The `%~dp0` variable contains the path where the batch file is located see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10290765/8051589.

**6.
Block redirection `( ... )>>`:**

To redirect multiple commands at once you can open a block `(`, execute commands, close the block `)` and use a redirection. You could also execute every command and redirect that only that would have the same effect.

Comment: How would I delete (or clear) the list.txt file before writing to it?

Comment: @Nalgene5622: I extend my answer with explanations to meet your request. Also the batch script would create a new file first and overwrites it if it already exists. Hope that helps! If you have more questions feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

There are so many ways to do this. For example, using the [Wolfram Language](https://www.wolfram.com/language/) you can:

```
StringJoin @@ 
    FileSystemMap[
        If[FileExtension[#] == "txt", Import[#, "Text"]] &, 
        "C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\DummyFolder\\", Infinity, 1]
```

An then write the result using

```
Export[C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\, %, "Text"]
```

You can also do this with Python, Perl, etc.. use PowerShell only if you need to share your solution and want to avoid installers. I would not spend too much time learning 1981 technology (CMD).

Answer (score 0):

This may be a simple answer for what you are looking for, the usebackq is important to allow "" around paths. tokens=* to include all information. To use in a console instead of a batch file change %% to %.

```
    for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /s /b C:\testpath\*.txt') do (for /f "usebackq tokens=*"  %%b in ("%%a") do (echo %%b >> C:\test.txt))
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your source files are located in immediate sub-directories of the root directory `DummyFolder` and that you want the content of `Headings.txt` to occur once only on top of the resulting file, you could accomplish your task using the following script:

```cmd
@echo off

rem // Define constants here:
set "folder=C:\Users\user\Desktop\DummyFolder"
set "header=%folder%\Headings.txt"
set "result=%folder%\merged.txt"

rem // Prepare result file, copy content of header file:
copy "%header%" "%result%" > nul
rem // Enumerate immediate sub-directories of the given root directory:
for /D %%D in ("%folder%\*") do (
    rem // Enumerate matching files per sub-directory:
    for %%F in ("%%~D\*.txt") do (
        rem // Append content of current file to result file:
        copy /Y "%result%" + "%%~F" "%result%" /B > nul
    )
)
```

---

In case your source files are located anywhere in the directory tree `DummyFolder`, you need to make sure that the header file `Headings.txt` and the result file `merged.txt` are not iterated:

```cmd
@echo off

rem // Define constants here:
set "folder=C:\Users\user\Desktop\DummyFolder"
set "header=Headings.txt"
set "result=merged.txt"

rem // Prepare result file, copy content of header file:
copy "%folder%\%header%" "%folder%\%result%" > nul
rem // Enumerate matching files in the whole given directory tree:
for /R "%folder%" %%F in ("*.txt") do (
    rem // Exclude the header file to be re-processed:
    if /I not "%%~nxF"=="%header%" (
        rem // Exclude the result file to be processed:
        if /I not "%%~nxF"=="%result%" (
            rem // Append content of current file to result file:
            copy /Y "%folder%\%result%" + "%%~F" "%folder%\%result%" /B > nul
        )
    )
)
```