# Batch file command differences

Tags: batch-file, command, symbols

I am new to batch scripting and wonder if anyone would help me understand the differences below:

Differences between these 3 lines:

```
Set "File=Test.txt"
Set File="Test.txt"
Set File=Test.txt
```

Differences between these 3 lines:

```
Set /A "Start=3"
Set Start=3
Call Set /A "Start=3"
```

Difference between these 2 lines:

```
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
@SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
```

What does this line do?

```
break > %outfile%
```

Thank you for your help.

I have tried writing basic scripts and trying the minor differences but didn't see much change.  Just wonder why the different way of writing it.

Comment: Please read [Why is no string output with 'echo %var%' after using 'set var = text' on command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26388460/3074564) It explains the differences in full details with an example for demonstrating the differences.

Comment: `@` at beginning of a command line instructs `cmd` not printing the command line after parsing before execution. That is only necessary if the first line in the batch file is not `@echo off` which turns off the command echo mode with `@` used to prevent getting output this command line itself before execution. Please open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/), run `cmd /?` and read the output help. It is also possible to start `cmd.exe` with option `/Q` to turn echo off, but that is not the default on starting `cmd.exe` for batch file processing with a batch file double click.

Comment: `break > %outfile%` creates an empty file with a file size of 0 bytes overwriting an existing file, except the existing file has the read-only attribute set. I have never seen a batch file where this command is really necessary. The first output of a string can be always redirected with redirection operator `>` into a file creating the file new even on already existing and all other strings are appended to the once created file with redirection operator `>>`. There is no need to first create the output file with a file size of 0 bytes on having a line which always writes the first line.

Comment: I suggest further reading the __issue__ chapters in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60686543/3074564) and [debugging a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42448601/3074564) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67039507/3074564) for details about the commands __SETLOCAL__ and __ENDLOCAL__ as well as [How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094699/)

Comment: Thank you everyone for your replies.  I've really learnt a lot from just this one post.  You guys are a great resource.  Thanks again for sharing your knowledge and being a great teacher.

Answer (score 1):

1. 

`Set "File=Test.txt"` - safest way when the value contains special characters

`Set File="Test.txt"` - the value will include the quotes

`Set File=Test.txt` - in this case it will be the same as the first approach

2)

`Set /A "Start=3"` - the switch indicates that there will be [arithmetic e expression](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html). Though here it is just "3" so it will be the same with and without "/A".

`Set Start=3` - just simple assigning start to 3

`Call Set /A "Start=3"` - used when it is set inside brackets section and the value contains another variable. Usually is better to use [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html). [Here](https://ss64.com/nt/call.html) you can see more detailed explanation

3)
the `@` at the beginning of the line will not print the command itself ,but only the output (if there's any). Same as `echo off` but applied only for one line. There should not be a space after the `@`

4)
`break > %outfile%` - [clears the content](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19633987/388389) of the `%outfile%`

Comment: Thank you npocmaka for all your simple to understand answers.